# SVN connection issue

Tags: svn

I have one SVN server in data center and I have one SVN server at the office.
I checked out code into SVN server at the office this code is from data center.
I created SVN repository at the office that points code from Data center code.
I checked out code in office svn into my local machine.
So here is the issue.
I update code in the office server pointing data center svn. it works fine.
After updating svn, I update code in my local machine it dosen't work.
I can see the change in office svn but i cannot update my local svn.
So the whole picture is like that the code in office server pointing data center svn repository  I created the repository in office server pointing the code in the office server that points data center repository. I have code in my local machine pointing office server repository. If you update code in the office server. why you cannot update code in local machine. In theory, It should work.
Any thought?

Comment: What? You should clarify your question and describe the steps you performed explicitly. What do you mean by "I checked out code into SVN server at the office this code is from data center" or by "I update code in the office server pointing data center svn"? Do you mean 'svnsync'?